# Что делает аннотация @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

В документации мало про это написано, но насколько я понял, она глобально включает security на методы, но в чем тогда разница между ней и @EnableWebSecurity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@EnableWebSecurity` вам требуется если вы хотите написать конфигурацию `HttpSecurity`, `WebSecurity`, `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http){
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .hasRole("USER").and()
        .formLogin()
        .permitAll();
}
```

---

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` включает AOP для конкретных методов или классов с помощью аннотаций `@PreAuthorized`, `@PostAuthorize`  и т.п.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public List<String> getUserPasswords() {
  return userService.passwords();
}
```